# Mac Program to Get the Latex code of a PDF

Tags: mac

I am writing a math paper that uses some long equations from PDFs. Are there any converters from Pdf to Latex?

Comment: Indeed EverythingEnds, but it is not good to end a sentence in the middle ...

Comment: The linked answer says no though, @albert

Comment: I admit that it is very difficult, but t looks to me that there are some, incomplete, possibilities under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `Math Snipping Tool` which is a cross-platform tool from [here](https://mathpix.com/). If you provide some typed or (neatly written) text, it will generate the `LaTeX` code for the same.